# Did Cirdan the Shipwright have a wife?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, cirdan

Cirdan by the time of the events of Lord of the Rings is the Eldest/One of the eldest Elves in Middle earth living at least 10,000 years maybe more and i want to know if it known if he was married or was just a chastitied Elf who hadn't found an Elf maiden to wed?

Answer (score 7):

### Most likely not

Círdan had travelled across Middle-earth with Olwë and the Teleri. As he was preparing to make his own crossing, Círdan claimed he would follow the light from Valinor "Alone if none will come with [him]". This suggests that he had no tie to a spouse, and if he had, she had gone before. Before he could sail, he felt a message from the Valar ask him to wait, to shepherd those Elves who would later come across the Sea and only himself sail forth, Last of the Elves.

> Then, it is said, he stood forlorn looking out to sea, and it was
> night, but far away he could see a glimmer of light upon Eressea
> ere it vanished into the West. Then he cried aloud: 'I will follow
> that light, **alone if none will come with me**, for the ship that I
> have been building is now almost ready.' But even as he said this
> he received in his heart a message, which he knew to come from
> the Valar, though in his mind it was remembered as a voice
> speaking in his own tongue. And the voice warned him not to
> attempt this peril; for his strength and skill would not be able
> to build any ship able to dare the winds and waves of the Great
> Sea for many long years yet. '**Abide now that time, for when
> it comes then will your work be of utmost worth**, and it will
> be remembered in song for many ages after.' 'I obey,' Cirdan
> answered, and then it seemed to him that he saw (in a vision
> maybe) a shape like a white boat, shining above him, that sailed
> west through the air, and as it dwindled in the distance it looked
> like a star of so great a brilliance that it cast a shadow of Cirdan
> upon the strand where he stood.
> As we now perceive, this was a foretelling of the ship (37) which
> after apprenticeship to Cirdan, and ever with his advice and
> help, Earendil built, and in which at last he reached the shores
> of Valinor. From that night onwards Cirdan received a foresight
> touching all matters of importance, beyond the measure of all
> other Elves upon Middle-earth.
> <sub>History of Middle-earth XII, Last Writings</sub>

As I'd said before, if he had had a partner, it's most likely she'd crossed the sea on the island that would become Tol Eressëa.

> Thus he forfeited the fulfilment of his greatest desire: to see the Blessed Realm and find again there Olwë and his own nearest kin.

This is however never touched on and Círdan having a wife is possible.

Answer (score 6):

If he did she was never mentioned.  Though immortal, Elves tended to marry or have children only when they were young for the most part.  So as the ages passed on, he would have presumably lost any interest that he might have had when he was younger.

Comment: Worth noting he was sworn to his post, who knows if he had time to find a wife.